# database server not found 08w01 using Sybase Database

Tags: connection-string, sybase, host, sqlanywhere

I'm trying to access a hosted database. The latter is a Sybase database, version of SQL AnyWhere 12. I'm using the following connectiong string as descriped in the Sybase documentation.

```
... DBN=Test;DBF=c:\temp\test.db;ASTART=YES;ASTOP=NO;LINKS=TCPIP {host=10.10.10.10;dobroadcast=no};COMP=NO ...
```

Now, when I try to use it in my application I get the error

> Error 100 ... database server not found 08w01

Any idea how this issue be fixed,

Thanks,

Comment: Sybase was a company not a database.  You should specify which database product and version you are trying to run.  From the connection string it looks like it might be SQL Anywhere.

Comment: thanks, done. As I know Sybase has only one product database? did you have any idea how to fix the error I get?

Comment: Sybase ASE, Sybase IQ, SQL Anywhere, ASA, Mobilink are all Sybase database products.  I work with ASE primarily, so I don't know the cuase of your issue. I've added the [sqlanywhere] tag to get it better visibility with the right people.

Comment: Are you sure the database is running?  Sounds as though its not running or the interface doesn't know where to look for it.

Comment: You are right, I use a bad SQL Anywhere driver and this is why I got the error. Thanks for help